# pglogical library

Tags: postgresql, replication, transactional-replication, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I would like to try `pglogical` to set up an `archive server` from a live database, filtering with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` statements (`DELETE` statements will not be replicated in the `archive server`).
I follow the [official documentation](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/) but when i set `shared_preload_libraries` = `'pglogical'` in my configuration file (`postgresql.conf`) the server could not start.

There is no pglogical file in `./usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/` directory.

How setting up all prerequisites to start properly (with v9.5 and 9.6)?
I am using PostgreSQL v9.5 and v9.6 for POC on CentOS 7.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I miss download this
`yum install postgresql96-pglogical`